# Kendo GRID - After the click on the "Add new row" button get kendo grid Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of 'name' null

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

im trying to add new row in Kendo Grid with following settings:

```
costCategory: {
                editable: true,
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: {},
                type: "object"
              },
```

And editable set to:

```
editable:{
        //mode: 'inline',
        //confirmation:false //remove delete confirm message
      },
```

But after the click on the "Add new row " button i always get following error message;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of nullVM6703:3 (anonymous function)jquery.js:547 proxykendo.all.min.js:24 N.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend._rowsHtmlkendo.all.min.js:24 N.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend._renderContentkendo.all.min.js:24 N.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend.refreshjquery.js:547 proxykendo.all.min.js:9 n.extend.triggerkendo.all.min.js:11 ct.extend._processkendo.all.min.js:11 ct.extend._changejquery.js:547 proxykendo.all.min.js:9 n.extend.triggerkendo.all.min.js:10 ct.extend.splicekendo.all.min.js:11 ct.extend.insertkendo.all.min.js:23 N.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend.addRowkendo.all.min.js:23 (anonymous function)jquery.js:4641 jQuery.event.dispatchjquery.js:4309 elemData.handle
```

Could it be caused value in column?

```
  {
          field :"costCategory.name",
          title : $translate.instant('COSTCATEGORY'),
          width: "200px",
          editor: GlobalHelperService.getCostCategoryForAutocomplete,
          filterable: {
            cell: {
              operator: "contains"
            }
          }
        },
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: There is no such type `object`. Valid values can be found in [schema.model.define](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#methods-Model.define). I.e. the available options are "string", "number", "boolean", "date". The default is "string".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
costCategory: {
                editable: true,
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: {"name" : ""},
                type: "object"
              },
```